# Add JavaScript to all WooCommerce Products

Tags: javascript, woocommerce-offtopic

Does anyone know how to add JavaScript to all WooCommerce products?
From what I've read, I might need to upload the code on my server as a .js and then point to it via a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do this on the single product page use this condition then enqueue the JavaScript files.

```
function enqueue_single_product_javascript()
{
    if(is_product())
    {
       // Use wp_enqueue_script()
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_single_product_javascript');
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response!
Can you please provide a little more detail as I'm getting an fatal error.

I am trying:
`wp_enqueue_script('script', 'urlpath'/chat.js')`

Comment: Can you post a copy of the function you're enqueueing your script on? Also, what does the error say?